# Changing User Agent

Tags: iphone, objective-c, http, header, user-agent

I am trying to change my user agent like this

```
[req setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
```

Where userAgent is an NSString and it seems to work in the app because when I NSLog it it shows up as what I changed it to

```
NSLog(@"user agent = %@", [req valueForHTTPHeaderField: @"User-Agent"]);
```

But when I go to this site http://whatsmyuseragent.com/ the user agent is unchanged. Does anyone know why this could be.

Thanks
Clinton

Comment: Setting the user-agent is only good for that request, unless you are using that req object to go to that website it will be your default user agent for your device.

Comment: Is there anyway to change the default user agent?

Comment: Not w/o jailbreaking or using an app like Perfect Browser. If your project has a browser (webview) you just need to set the user agent for each request.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the site with Browser like Safari , the user agent is unchanged . 
You set the value is just for your Request one time  , not for the browser or all the request .